# Debug String value and getBytes produce different results

Tags: java, string, encoding

```
byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();

// prints -61 -68 -61 -74 

data.value(); // This method is package private, I used debugger.
// -4 -10
```

Why these arrays are different?

[image: Bytes in debug]    String data = "üö";

Comment: Do you know that `byte` and `char` are not the same? The `byte` data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer. The `char` data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character.

Comment: Im pretty sure this is due to Java 9's Compact String changes. Check out https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-compact-string . I dont know enough about the subject to really speak to it but maybe someone else can :)

Comment: value() and value_ are private to the implementation of String.  You cannot have a reasonable expectation that they will ever produce anything useful to you.  What matters is the accuracy of the values returned by public methods.